# Jquery find - increase of number

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a simple jQuery function as I was just trying to find that best way to write this. So basically,I want the correct div to find the correct contact form. E.g. cf1 will show contactform1, cf2 will find contactform2 etc... What is the best way to write this, rather then duplicating and writing this code multiple times?

```
$('.cf1').parent().parent().parent().find('.contactform1').show();
$('.cf2').parent().parent().parent().find('.contactform2').show();
$('.cf3').parent().parent().parent().find('.contactform3').show();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function.

Example Code

```
$('.cf1').closest('.contactform1').show();
$('.cf2').closest('.contactform2').show();
$('.cf3').closest('.contactform3').show();
```

Comment: But I want to write this as 1 code, rather then duplicating loads of these

Comment: Is this example useful: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/MWjWeBV

Answer (score 0):

You must use both, [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) jquery methods.

With the `closest` method you go up to an element which is parent of both your elements (eg. `.cf1` and `.contactform1`), then with the `find` method you will go down to find the right form.

```js
$('.cf1').closest('.selector-parent-of-both').find('.contactform1').show();
$('.cf2').closest('.selector-parent-of-both').find('.contactform2').show();
$('.cf3').closest('.selector-parent-of-both').find('.contactform3').show();
```